# Oracle merge on column with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have two tables in oracle database

```
"persons" with columns (personid, lastname, firstname, address, city)
"person_details" with columns (id, personid, mobileno)
```

and a merge table

```
"merge_test" with columns (personid, detail_id, lastname, firstname, address, city, mobileno)
```

and i am using following merge statement

```
merge into merge_test
using ( select p.personid personid,
            d.id detailid,
            p.firstname firstname,
            p.lastname lastname,
            p.address address,
            p.city city,
            d.mobileno mobileno
        from persons p
            left outer join person_details d
            on p.personid = d.personid ) source
on ( 
  merge_test.personid = source.personid
  and nvl(merge_test.detail_id, nvl(source.detailid, 0)) = nvl(source.detailid, 0)
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
    merge_test.firstname = source.firstname,
    merge_test.lastname = source.lastname,
    merge_test.address = source.address,
    merge_test.city = source.city,
    merge_test.mobileno = source.mobileno
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (personid, detail_id, lastname, firstname, address, city, mobileno)
  values (source.personid, source.detailid, source.lastname, source.firstname, source.address, source.city, source.mobileno);
```

in here merge_test.detail_id will be null initially and can get multiple values for a persons.personid ( multiple rows for a single merge_test.person_id), and merge statement will run every hour.

i want to merge in such a way that value of merge_test.detail_id gets updated if value of source.detailid gets updated and new row get inserted for multiple rows of source.detailid.

**Edit 13-03-2020**

The above query will run every hour and merge_test will be updated using merge query.

for a persons table with data like

```
personid, lastname, firstname, address, city
1, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city'
2, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city'
3, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city'
```

for a person_details table with data like

```
id, personid, mobileno
1, 1, 'mobileno'
2, 1, 'mobileno'
3, 2, 'mobileno'
```

will result in merge_test table like below

```
personid, detail_id, lastname, firstname, address, city, mobileno
1, 1, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
1, 2, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
2, 3, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
3, null, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
```

above data is generated with select statement and left outer join

when person_detail table gets updated by below detais

```
id, personid, mobileno
1, 1, 'mobileno'
2, 1, 'mobileno'
3, 1, 'mobileno'
4, 3, 'mobileno'
```

the merge test table should be updated as

```
personid, detail_id, lastname, firstname, address, city, mobileno
1, 1, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
1, 2, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
1, 3, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
2, null, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
3, 4, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
```

i want query that can handle that kind of manipulation with data and store that data in merge_test table

Comment: isnt (detail_id,person_id) the primary key combination in the person_details table. In this case how is it possible for the detail_id to get "updated". You could be updating the attributes associated with a person_details ie(mobileno). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, the thing is that at **first row will not be present for personid** in person_details table. after some hours a **row will get inserted for personid in person_details**, _so table with left outer join statement will result in row with detail_id updated_. and multiple rows can be added for a single personid  in person_details table.

Comment: So do you want the record to be created with null values the first time and later on to delete these nulls and use up only filled values of detail_id

Comment: yes, i want to store null value first time and later update null with incoming value from select statement, and if more than one value occurs then create a new row rather than updating it

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

Following the delete, you would have an update to set to null the records which have missing entries in person_detail table in MERGE_TEST table..

Just to be sure the intermediate answer would have the values as follows

```
personid, detail_id, lastname, firstname, address, city, mobileno
1, 1, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
1, 2, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
2, 3, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', 'mobileno'
3, null, 'lname', 'fname', 'add', 'city', null /*This should be null?*/
```

I believe you want to lose the nvl logic in the on clause and include a delete statement following the MERGE as follows to cater to the cases you have talked about

(your merge query);

```
DELETE
  FROM merge_test a
 WHERE a.detail_id is null
   AND EXISTS (select 1 /* This block checks if we have a not_null details_id for the person_id and if so then delete the NULL entry*/
                 FROM merge_Test b
                WHERE a.person_id=b.person_id
                  AND a.detail_id=b.detail_id
              );

 UPDATE merge_test a
    SET a.detail_id=NULL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                      from person_details b
                     where b.id=a.person_id);
```

Comment: i also want to store null value if value doesn't exist in person_details table

Comment: Yes that will not delete the nulls unless that person has a not null detail id

Comment: I tried to run this delete query after removing NVL from my merge query, it doesn't delete any rows which are null and non null rows are added for a perticular person_id. the thing is that a non null detailid can also be set to null if row was deleted from person_details table, so need to handle that too

Comment: is that the expectation

Comment: yes, need to handle detail_id as a updatable field which can contain null, one value or multiple values for a person_id.

Comment: im not sure if i understand this fully. Can you update the question and include test rows and the expected output